# Dagger 2 - Sharing Instances between two activities

Tags: android, dagger-2

I have an issue when using Dagger 2. I have really liked the changes made between Dagger 1 and Dagger 2 but today I hit a wall.

The issue is regarding Scopes.

I am following a MVP architecture. I have two activities (a list and details) and I want both of them to share a presenter. The reason for it is that the presenter handles pagination and the details view has a view pager and I want to be able to keep paginating inside the details view when swiping the pager.

Currently I have two components: **ItemComponent** and **AppComponent**

```
@ApplicationScope
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, UIModule.class, DataModule.class})
public interface AppComponent extends AppGraph { 
    //Application Scoped dependencies
}

@ItemScope
@Component(
    dependencies = AppComponent.class,
    modules = ItemModule.class)
public interface ItemComponent {

    void inject(final ItemDetailsActivity itemDetailsActivity);

    void inject(final ItemDetailsFragment itemDetailsFragment);

    void inject(final ItemListActivity itemListActivity);
}
```

The ItemComponent has one Module: **ItemModule**
The ItemModule provides **ItemPresenter**

```
@Module
public class ItemModule {

private ItemDetailsActivity itemDetailsActivity;
private ItemDetailsFragment itemDetailsFragment;
private ItemListActivity itemListActivity;

public ItemModule(final ItemDetailsActivity itemDetailsActivity) {
    this.itemDetailsActivity = itemDetailsActivity;
}

public ItemModule(final ItemDetailsFragment itemDetailsFragment) {
    this.itemDetailsFragment = itemDetailsFragment;
}

public ItemModule(final ItemListActivity itemListActivity) {
    this.itemListActivity = itemListActivity;
}

// The presenter that handles the pagination
@Provides
@ItemScope
public ItemListPresenter provideItemListPresenter(final ItemService itemService) {
    return new ItemListPresenter(itemService);
}
}
```

All of which have the scope **ItemScope**

But in both activities I need to initialise the component and the module and therefore a new instance of the presenter is provided. I have read through multiple answers here on StackOverflow and I have figured out that this should be solved with Component dependencies and / or SubComponent but I haven't been able to get it working.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: since (with great simplification) there cannot be 2 valid instences of Activity derived classes at the same time what is the point of this?

Comment: That is not what I am aiming for. I aim to have one instance of the ListPresenter accessible from the ListActivity as well as the DetailsActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Wether you use components with dependencies or subcomponents is entirely up to you—the main difference is about which objects get provided to dependencies / subcomponents.

You are mixing 2 scopes here: Item and Activity scope. You would include another scope inbetween like the following:

```
App Scope -> Item Scope -> (List) Activity Scope
                  \-> (Detail) Activity Scope
```

If you actually have a scope that is 'above' the activities depending on it, you can share the objects it provides.

Create the `ItemComponent` and keep it in e.g. your `Application` to be shared. Then, when injecting your activities, additionally to the `AppComponent` you'd include the `ItemComponent`—thus sharing dependencies between List and Detail Activities.

Your `ItemsModule` will then just provide the `Presenter` or some other dependency with which your actual provider can handle paging / scrolling.

Comment: Okay thanks, this is somehow similar to what I had already done. But if I do it this way, that is share the ItemComponent through the Application, wouldn't the Item scope really just be like the App Scope ? That is, only one instance throughout the App and not only during the lifetime of the List Activity?

Comment: @palmithor I have the same question. Did you find out the answer? I suspect the key is the scope. I guess that, while the same component is shared, the provide methods work according to the scope. Let me know.

Comment: @rpattabi Unfortunately I don't remember how I solved this. If I remember correctly I didn't succeed in doing it the way I describe here above.